# Absolute Center (Vertical & Horizontal) "Responsive" it does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, swiper.js

I'm use Bootstrap 3.3.5 and demo 30-lazy-load-images, The problem is that the container can not have a fixed height(px), it must be "100% or auto" for it to be compatible with the responsive design.

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9s75kkxp/3/)

```
.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px; // Only work if star height eg 500px, but need this container responsive 100% or auto.
```

}

[image]

If set height: 100% or auto, .swiper-container height not initialize "0". How can we solve this? the image must be centered like the lazy load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **height:50vh;** to have the swiper-container display half of the screen height. Or whatever you want to set this height at.
Then this will be responsive.

```
.swiper-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50vh;
    }
```

Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9s75kkxp/4/)**.

For some more info about using **vh** **[please read this](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/)**.